# Triggering timestamp on formula input

Tags: google-sheets, google-apps-script, automation, google-sheets-timestamp

I'd like to have a timestamp which triggers its input depending on a cell containing a formula like `=IF(ISBLANK(cell),"", time )`, and not upon manual input.

My script is the following and is working just fine in case of manual input:

```
function onEdit() {
  var s = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSheet();
  if (s.getName()=='my sheet'){
  var r = s.getActiveCell();
  if( r.getColumn() == 3 && r != '') { //checks the column
    var row = r.getRow();
    var time = new Date();
    time = Utilities.formatDate(time, "GMT+02:00", "MM/dd/yyyy hh:mm:ss");
    SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSheet().getRange("E" + row.toString()).setValue(time);
  }
  else if( r.getColumn() == 4 && r != '') { //checks the column
    var row = r.getRow();
    var time = new Date();
    time = Utilities.formatDate(time, "GMT+02:00", "MM/dd/yyyy hh:mm:ss");
    SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSheet().getRange("F" + row.toString()).setValue(time);
  }
  }
}
```

Is there a way to make it depend on a formula?

Comment: I don't understand when exactly you want the timestamp to be added. If a particular cell is not blank now, it will probably remain not blank next minute. What is the _event_ that should trigger adding a timestamp.

Comment: @HomegrownTomato the mentioned trigger is a conditional formula which will fill the cell with its information - IF('cell 1'='cell 2',"condition validated","")

Answer (score 1):

See if this works:

```
function onEdit(e) {
    var cols = [3, 4];
    if (e.source.getActiveSheet().getName() !== 'my sheet' || cols.indexOf(e.range.columnStart) === -1) return;
    var t = Utilities.formatDate(new Date(), "GMT+02:00", "MM/dd/yyyy hh:mm:ss");
    e.range.offset(0, 2).setValue(isFormula(e.source.getActiveSheet(), e.range.getA1Notation()) ? t : null);
}

function isFormula(sheet, range) {
    return sheet.getRange(range).getFormula() ? true : false;
}
```